# Select Some Strings From Event message

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pull all **username,time created and public ip** address from

Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational event.

[image]

I get all the events from messages with below command but I need only username,and ip

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303}
```

Trying with this No luck

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303}| select timecreated  -expand Message [regex]::Match($event, 'user:\s*(.*)\s*').Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a better approach using the `ToXml()` Method on the EventLogRecord Object:

First Catch the Events:

```
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303}
```

Then, Take for example the first item in the array and convert it to XML:

```
[xml]$Event = $Events[0].ToXml()
```

Now you can see all the Information you need:

```
$Event.Event.UserData.EventInfo
```

**Update:** Set it for you, this should do the work:

```
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303}

$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ($Event in $Events)
{
[xml]$Xml = $Event.ToXml()
$Row = "" | Select Username,TimeCreated,IPAddress
$Row.Username = $Xml.Event.UserData.EventInfo.Username
$Row.TimeCreated = $Event.TimeCreated.ToString()
$Row.IPAddress = $Xml.Event.UserData.EventInfo.IpAddress
[void]$ArrayList.Add($Row)
}

$ArrayList
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: this works you messed provider name

`$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303}

$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ($Event in $Events)
{
[xml]$Xml = $Event.ToXml()
$Row = "" | Select Username,TimeCreated,IPAddress
$Row.Username = $Xml.Event.UserData.EventInfo.Username
$Row.TimeCreated = $Event.TimeCreated.ToString()
$Row.IPAddress = $Xml.Event.UserData.EventInfo.IpAddress
[void]$ArrayList.Add($Row)
}

$ArrayList`

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I can see what you're trying with the `Select` command, and while it sounds good, that doesn't quite work. What you could do instead is pass it through a `Where` statement matching the string you need, and capturing the relevant data in a RegEx match, then using `Select` to add those fields onto the object.

So a `Where` match that would work for you should be:

```
| Where{$_.Message -match '"(.+?\\.+?)".+"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"'}
```

Then you pipe to `Select` and build the User and IPAddress properties on the fly like this:

```
| Select TimeCreated,@{l='User';e={$Matches[1]}},@{l='IPAddress';e={$Matches[2]}}
```

Then you put it all together and you get:

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303} | Where{$_.Message -match '"(.+?\\.+?)".+"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"'} | Select TimeCreated,@{l='User';e={$Matches[1]}},@{l='IPAddress';e={$Matches[2]}}
```

Using that with some randomized values I was able to output:

```
TimeCreated          User           IPAddress     
-----------          ----           ---------     
9/14/2016 9:47:29 AM DOMAIN\dhxrjqb 216.229.149.87
9/14/2016 9:47:29 AM DOMAIN\fkoilrh 236.65.23.77  
9/14/2016 9:47:29 AM DOMAIN\mvibope 20.7.45.231
```

Ok, the solution to the issue that you noted in your comment is a minor tweak to the RegEx match to make one portion not greedy. This would do that:

```
| Where{$_.Message -match '"(.+?\\.+?)".+?"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"'}
```

and all together again...

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway/Operational" ; ID = 300,302,303} | Where{$_.Message -match '"(.+?\\.+?)".+?"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"'} | Select TimeCreated,@{l='User';e={$Matches[1]}},@{l='IPAddress';e={$Matches[2]}}
```

Comment: awesome but in some users its just adding ip from connected to resource like "10.10.1" of local computer

Comment: Can you give an example of a message where it is doing that?

Comment: Ok I got it on event it 302 the event has 2 ips `The user "doaminuser", on client computer "10.255.188.2", connected to resource "172.10.1.1".`

Comment: can we select two ipaddresses one as local and other as public we will just delete csv header no hard work on powershell